# Connect to Enterprise GDB in PostgreSQL using QGIS : "No Geometry" Error

Tags: qgis, postgresql, geometry, esri-geodatabase

I have an esri Enterprise Geodatabase (9.3) stored in MSSql 2008 with storage type as sde binary.

I upgraded it to EGDB 10.4.1 (using multiple up-gradation steps) in MSSql 2012.

Then I copy/paste my data to PostgreSQL(9.4). I have the storage type in PostgreSQL as high precision `ST_Geometry` spatial type (SRID 300001).

I tried to connect to PostgreSQL geodatabase using QGIS but all my data are showing as `no geometry` and hence I cannot view it in QGIS.

However I can connect to it using ArcMap.

How do I solve this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you defined geometry for the table?

Comment: Do you have PostGIS installed? Can you see the data in the spatial viewer in either PGAdmin4 or DBeaver?

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar i didnot deifne the geometry manually. I just migrated the data from MSSQL 2012(which has data type as sde binary) to postgreSQL using copy/paste in arcgis.

Comment: @DPSSpatial yes i have postgis(2.3)insatlled. i can see tables but cannot view in spatial viewer both in pgadmin 4 and Dbeaver.

Comment: @tsering can you post the result of a query that selects the geometry and what is shown in the results window?

Comment: @DPSSpatial I have posted a screenshot above.